# Why DatePicker is returning a null after when post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Here is my problem so after the Data is successfully created, All the data is inserted into the database.
So I wanted to edit the info, the others field works fine but the DatePicker is broken

After I pressed **Save** which is post the data it will become 01/01/0001

I checked it the value were supposed to had "27/11/2020" but if I not rechose the date again it will become 01/01/0001

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { id = "Date", placeholder = "", @class = "form-control datepicker"})
```

Comment: you have to follow the date-picker documentation in order to set or get date

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think is that the MVC is only accept DD-MM-YYY for the Date Format, So if you use 12/12/2020, It won't accept it and turn it into 01-01-0001